# How to use script to insert a formula when there's an empty cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one spreadsheet that has all my website's pricing. I run a script to convert the spreadsheet into a format that I can upload to my website. But sometimes I have a cost price but the supplier doesn't provide a Recommended Retail Price (RRP). So when I upload the file, some products end up with a price of $0.00.

I'm trying to get the following working, but I reckon I'm missing something. The RRP is in skuData[i][6] or column G in the original spreadsheet. Column F has the cost price in the original spreadsheet or `skuData[i][5]` I guess.

```
// When No RRP
if (skuData[i][6].isBlank()) {
cell.setValue("=ROUND((F2*1.3),0)-0.01");
}
```

I'm trying to make it do the following:

If price is 100 and RRP is empty then make RRP 129.99

Comment: Can you clarify the reason why you cannot just go `cell.setValue(Math.round(skuData[i][5] * 1.3) - .01);` and set the value and be done with it?  Why does it have to be a formula?

Comment: I didn't know how to achieve the $X.99 rather than just rounding to the nearest $ amount.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that cell is a Range there is a [setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String)) function that you can use.  Also assuming that skuData[i][6] is the two dimensional array returned by  getValues() then you can just check that it is blank by using a == comparison.

```
// When No RRP
if (skuData[i][6] == "") {
    cell.setValue("=ROUND((F2*1.3),0)-0.01");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think I might be out of my depth. The error I go was... "Cannot find function isBlank in object 63.9. I presume I missing something like setting a variable so that all values in my price column are defined, and similar for the actual calculation.